# Unable to import firebase module inside firebase-messaging-sw.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, firebase, push-notification

Im working on firebase messaging service to send push notification via django web application to web app on Andriod,IOS and website as well, I managed to get token and run sw ,however i can't running sw and get messages due to importing module issue, I tried all import statements and none has worked with me!!,

when i run the below lines i got this error "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope':

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
```

and when i run these ones i got this error "Cannot use import statement outside a module":

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getMessaging } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-sw.js";
```

Note I do not have any error when accessing localhost:/firebase-messaging-sw.js and download window open to download firebase-messaging-sw.js file

please find firebase-messaging-sw.js files for your reference:

```
// import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js";
// import { getMessaging } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-sw.js";

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging.js');
self.importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-sw.js');

// import { initializeApp } from "./node_modules/@firebase/app";
// import { getMessaging } from "./node_modules/@firebase/messaging/sw";

// import { getMessaging } from "./firebase/@firebase/messaging/sw";



// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
const BikumApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  appId: "1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebae.getMessaging(BikumApp)
console.log(messaging);


// const messaging = getMessaging();
onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };
  
  registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried lower firebase version? like 8.10.0? Since version 9 using modular API, I think  that's the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I used the earlier version and it worked properly, the good thing they response timely to open issues on their GitHub repository at least JS sdk team are cooperated

Answer (score 0):

As `firebase-messaging-sw.js` is not a JavaScript module, you should use the
[compat libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade?hl=zh-cn#window-compat), like this:

```js
// 'https:' can be omitted
importScripts('//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js')
importScripts('//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js')
```

And use `firebase.messaging()` to get an instance of Firebase Messaging:

```js
const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(messaging, payload => {
    const options = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
        icon: payload.notification.image,
    }
    return self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, options)
})
```